# Checkout loading image not disappear after load all data and after place order not redirecting to sucess page in magento2

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.1.0

### ISSUE-1

Magento2 checkout module work on knockout js so when we go to checkout page it's default behaviour is first showing us a **Loading image** at that time in backend magento fetch all needed data  and when all data load it's show in checkout page and **Loading image** is disappear.

But in my case when all data is fetched and showing in checkout step but **Loading image** still there so user can't edit/update data and not proceed further means whole checkout system not work and can't place order.

So I checked **onepage.phtml** file on **app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/templates** path and I got **Loading image code**. code is below.

```
<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
    <div class="loader">
        <img src="<?php  echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
             alt="<?php  echo __('Loading...'); ?>"
             style="position: absolute;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Above code is responsible for Loading image but now I can't find that why this **div** is not **display:none** when all data show in page?

---

### ISSUE-2

For further checkout process I comment **Loading-image** **div** for now so I can change/edit/update all data and go to next step for payment and shipping. fill all data and submit **place order** button so again I can only see **Loading image** and not redirect to Success page. I check in admin/sales that order is placed successfully but still in frontend **Loading image is showing not redirect to Success page**.